# Counting strings via Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've created a simple scanner to count the number of strings in a .txt file. Each string is at nextLine. It counts wrong, every time it gives me the number 297, even there're more than 20 000 strings. The .txt file was created by another program I've coded, it takes links from websites and saves them with FileWriter and BufferedWriter into the .txt file. What could be wrong?

```
public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/myName/Desktop/test.txt"));
    String string = scanner.next();
    int count = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        string = scanner.next();
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }           
 }
}
```

Edit: example of strings:

```
yahoo.com
google.com
etc.
```

Comment: "more than 20 000 strings" Are you sure it's more than 20000 lines?

Comment: Strings like links. Yeah, I am sure - I've counted them in MS Word.

Comment: try using `scanner.hasNext()` see what happens.

Comment: One thing that doesn't look good is that you are reading `scanner.next();` when you declare `String string` and not count it. Another thing is that if you want to count how many lines there is you should use `nextLine`, not `next`.

Comment: You don't need `String string = scanner.next`, just `String string;`

Comment: A snippet of your text file would help

Comment: take the `println` out of your `while` loop, unless you want it to print out every number

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't bother me.

Comment: Show us some part of your data, what output it gives you and what result you expected.

Comment: Recommend me a US share server, I don't really know any.

Comment: Not sure if that is US but http://pastebin.com/ seems to be ok to share text. Also don't paste entire file, just some part that will not be calculated correctly by your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eYDSdjCf

Comment: If I use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` in loop and declare `String string = null;` at start I get numbers from 1 to 343 as output so it seems to work fine.

Comment: I still get 297. Maybe the .txt file is corrupted?

Comment: When you get 297 ware you using only data you posted?

Comment: Have you actually opened and looked at the text file in a text editor?

Comment: Yes, I've opened it in a text editor. I am using only data I posted.

Comment: Try printing each string you read in tour loop. Use `System.out.println(count + "> "+string);`. Maybe this will give you some clue. Right now I can't help you more.

Comment: Well, it ends at line 297 (look at pastebin) and that string is cut, it ends in half. Weird.

Comment: I don't know. I ran the text file (the snippet of your file) myself with the code I have below and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to test what the last String is:

```
public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/myName/Desktop/test.txt"));
        int count = 0;

        String string;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.println(count);  
   }
}
```

Comment: how do you know there's 20k items in the text file? And are they listed in a vertical order the way you posted?

Comment: Yeah, in a vertical order as I posted. I've counted them in MS Word and in my other program, as they were saved in a HashSet. HashSet.size().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using a nextLine and parsing can be more accurate

```
public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/myName/Desktop/test.txt"));
        String string = scanner.next();
        int count = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            count += string.split(" ").length;
            System.out.println(count);
        }           
     }
    }
```

Comment: There is probably not. Maybe you are using different string than you think. Maybe this method is not good for reading file, I have never seen it using Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/myName/Desktop/test.txt"));
    int count = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }           
 }
}
```

What answer you are getting on this?

Comment: great, now you are counting ROWS instead of Strings and even 5 minutes later I posted solution with nextLine...

Answer (score 0):

As a default the whitespace delimiter is taken for the scanner, but in this case you would want to have the \n character as delimiter right? You can use `Scanner.useDelimiter("\n");` for this.